# Need to get count of cases who are in new/working states

Tags: apex, custom-metadata

I have requirement to get case count with some conditions like created date and status. These both fields needs to be configurable.
I have built something like this and its working but reviewer saying we can write more better way. Not able to understand the exact issue/ better way to write this code. Can someone help here

```
public with sharing class GetCaseStats {
    public static void getCaseDetails(List<case>caseList) {
        list<caseSettings__mdt> csMetadata = [select Case_CreatedDate__c,Status__c from caseSettings__mdt];
        datetime createddate = csMetadata[0].Case_CreatedDate__c;
        string splitStatus = csMetadata[0].Status__c;
        List<string> statusVal = splitStatus.split(',');
        list<case> caseStatusList = new List<case>();
        caseStatusList = [select id,status,createddate  from case where createddate <:createddate];
        integer count =0;
        for(case c:caseStatusList) {
            if(statusVal.contains(c.status)) {
                system.debug('inside if***');
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
        system.debug('****Count*****'+count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the reviewer has not given you the answer, I guess they want this to be a learning activity for you. So will avoid giving the direct answer.  The problem here is you are retrieving Case records just to get a count. There are function in SOQL. See if they can help. Also check if you can incorporate the logic from the `if` block in the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer count =0;

for(case c: [select id,status,createddate  from case where createddate <:createddate AND status IN :splitStatus]){
count = count + 1;
}

This will reduce the number of lines of code and will limit the number of rows from SOQL.

1. Store the status in Set and use that set in the query.
2. Also you can use custom setting to store the CreatedDate and Status, so you wont have to query the custom metadata.